# NSUserDefaults Plist Creation Fails in Swift (but not Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm converting one of my projects from Objective-C to Swift and I've run into an odd snag. Consider the following code (executed in -applicationDidFinishLaunching)...

**Objective-C**

*Please excuse the messy one-liner*

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"]]];
```

In my Objective-C project this works as expected. If I run my application for the first time and no plist exists, the defaults are registered and saved into a new plist during the next -synchronize call. If the plist already exists but a value is missing, it'll add that value from defaults. Makes sense.

**Swift**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let plist = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Defaults", ofType: "plist")
defaults.registerDefaults(NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: plist!) as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
defaults.synchronize()
```

In my Swift-exclusive project, the defaults get registered into memory, but they're never written to disk when -synchronize is called. I can test and verify that the default values exist in memory immediately after the code above is executed if I log a value...

```
println(defaults.objectForKey("showUnread"))
```

But the values are never saved to the plist. Even if I update one of my bindings from the interface (all of which save and persist perfectly fine), the defaults are not saved for the missing values. In fact, a plist will never be created for my application until I update one of my bindings.

And yet my Objective-C project, an almost verbatim translation of my Swift project, is working perfectly. I must be overlooking something simple, but my searches on Google and Stack Overflow have come up empty.

**Troubleshooting Steps**

1. Created a new Swift project, copied Defaults.plist to the project and put the above code in -applicationDidFinishLoading. Exact same results.
2. Deleted app cache and plist, emptied trash and restarted.
3. I heard the cfprefsd process could be maintaining a link to the deleted files, but it works fine with the Objective-C code using the same bundle identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `registerDefaults` never persists any data (in either language). It's just a fallback when looking up a value that doesn't exist. Your expectation that the data should be written to disk is incorrect.

Your call to `synchronize` doesn't do anything because you haven't set any values in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I did know about `registerDefaults` not writing to disk, but I had always assumed its purpose was to create those values if they didn't exist. If `synchronize` doesn't commit the defaults to your plist, what purpose does `registerDefaults` serve? And why then would the same code in Objective-C save the values to the plist?

Comment: 1) The Objective-C code does not save the values registered as defaults. If you have data persisted, it is from some other code. 2) The purpose of `registerDefaults` is to provide an in-memory set of values used if a real value hasn't been saved yet for a given key.

Comment: I thought about your answer more after commenting and realized I asked a bunch of questions you already answered. So the only remaining question I suppose I have is what is the standard practice for populating `NSUserDefaults` on an application's first launch? Check for nil and `setObject`?

Comment: 1) Define "unexpectedly work in Objective-C". I use `registerDefaults` in my Objective-C apps and it does not persist the default values. 2) You don't. There is no need to populate `NSUserDefaults`. That's what `registerDefaults` is for. It allows you to define default values without needlessly writing a bunch of initial values to disk. Only call `setObject:` when you have an explicit value to save.

Comment: If I delete the plist and app cache and rebuild my app then quit the application without interacting with it, it will create the plist and the contents of my Defaults.plist will be saved within. Nowhere in my entire project do I use `setObject`. It relies exclusively on interface bindings. I won't argue the point, because I realize my oversight is likely in my Objective-C project now and not my Swift project like I had thought, but it does seem odd. The only interaction with `NSUserDefaults` at launch is the code in my question.